# How to make a CAGradientLayer follow a CGPath

Tags: ios, swift, quartz-graphics, quartz-core

Given a CAShapeLayer defining a path as in the picture below, I want to add a CAGradientLayer that follows the path of the shape layer.

For example, given a gradient from black->red:

- the top right rounded piece would be black,
- and if the slider was at 100, the top left would be red,
- and if the slider was at 50, then half the slider would be black (as below), and the visible gradient would go from black (top right) to a redish-black at the bottom

[image: The Green should become the gradient]

Every previous post I've found does not actually answer this question.
For example, because I can only add axial CAGradientLayers, I can kind-of do this (pic below), but you can see it's not correct (the top left ends up becoming black again). How do I make the gradient actually follow the path/mask

[image]

Comment: As you've found this question has been asked many, many times - and never answered, as far I can tell. I'm beginning to think it's not possible… but maybe this time the mystery will be cracked!

Comment: I sure hope so! A bunch of posts reference the fact that CAGradientLayerType only has .axial as an option - but there are two additional ones now (.radial and .conic) so I was hopeful, although neither solve the problem still :O.

Comment: This might be worth looking at: https://github.com/sfcd/SFProgressCircle

Comment: And another one: https://github.com/robertpankrath/GradientRingProgressView

Comment: check awesome-gradient for finding iOS example using CAGradientLayer follow a CGPath https://github.com/cruisediary/awesome-gradient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the simple circular shape path, the new conic gradient is great. I was able to get this immediately (this is a conic gradient layer masked by a circle shape layer):

[image]

I used red and green so as to show the gradient clearly. This doesn't seem to be identically what you're after, but I can't believe it will be very difficult to achieve your goals now that `.conic` exists.

```
class MyGradientView : UIView {
    override class var layerClass : AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        let lay = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
        lay.type = .conic
        lay.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5)
        lay.endPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0)
        lay.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.frame = self.bounds
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        let b = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: shape.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)))
        shape.path = b.cgPath
        shape.lineWidth = 10
        shape.lineCap = .round
        shape.strokeStart = 0.1
        shape.strokeEnd = 0.9
        shape.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        shape.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-.pi/2, 0, 0, 1)
        self.layer.mask = shape
    }
}
```

Comment: That's so bizarre, I tried it and mine looks super strange. I must be doing something slightly off. Glad pointing it out helped though! Can't use it with my min SDK in any case. I think I'll mark your answer as correct though because moving forward it'll probably help a lot of people

Comment: @user1366911 Added code to show you how to use a conic gradient.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg why come back here to discuss this? You're wasing this user's time and mod time. We're now cleaning up flags. It was your mistake to begin with. Don't abuse the person for not wanting to engage you. This is the second time I've been back on this post.

Answer (score 2):

Anybody on iOS 12 should go with Matt's suggestion or maybe use SFProgressCircle as DonMag suggested.

My solution:
I personally ended up adding two CAShapeLayers, each with a corresponding CAGradientLayer.

By programmatically splitting the slider in half as in the pic below, I was able to apply a top-to-bottom gradient on each side, which gives the effect I'm looking for. It's invisible to the user.

[image]